# Unable to get my product ids after constructing the handle in Shopify

Tags: for-loop, shopify, liquid

I've been hurting an issue since **hours**. I hope someone will be able to understand my issue and help if possible. I'll try to be as clear as I can :

I need to show all the reviews of all my product within their collection. My collections are constructed like this : They show only the **PARENT** products. To show you an exemple, all my parents product are constructed like this :

*Parent's product handle : **parenthandle***

All my parents product have 2 child products constructed like this :

*Child's product handle - tshirt man : **parenthandle-tshirt-man***

*Child's product handle - tshirt woman : **parenthandle-tshirt-woman***

To be able to show my Parent product reviews, I need to concat its child's product ids as only my child's product have reviews (thats the way my reviews app is made).

**So, now that you have the context, in my collection page, I constructed something like this :**

```
{% assign producthandles_homme = "" %}
{% assign producthandles_femme = "" %}
{% assign id_enfant_homme = "" %}
{% assign id_enfant_femme = "" %}
{% assign allinone = "" %}

    {% for product in collection.products %}
       
        // Here I'm gonna construct my child products handle from their parents handle, to be able to then get their ids

        {% assign producthandles_homme =  producthandles_homme | append: product.handle | append: '-tshirt-homme' %}
        {% assign producthandles_femme =  producthandles_femme | append: product.handle | append: '-tshirt-femme' %} 

        // Now I can get their id as I constructed their handle

        {% assign id_enfant_homme = all_products[producthandles_homme].id | append: product.id | append: ',' %}
        {% assign id_enfant_femme = all_products[producthandles_femme].id | append: product.id | append: ',' %}

        // Here what I want to do is to concat all the ids of all my child product to be able to display their reviews

        {% assign allinone = allinone | append: id_enfant_homme | append: id_enfant_femme %}
       
    {% endfor %}

    // Finally here I want to display them all in "data-product-id"
    <div class="avis-verifies-etoiles-collection">
      <div class="NETREVIEWS_PRODUCT_STARS" data-product-id="{{ allinone }}"></div>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work, and I can't understand why. Sometimes it repeats the same id, sometimes no, all kind of ids are displaying :

[Here is the screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SLek.png)

Does someone would be able to help me ? I hope I was clear!

Thank you in advance!!!
Coline

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `for` loop with the following:

```
{%- liquid
  for product in collection.products
    assign producthandles_homme =  product.handle | append: '-tshirt-homme'
    assign producthandles_femme =  product.handle | append: '-tshirt-femme'

    if all_products[producthandles_homme] != blank
      assign allinone = allinone | append: ',' | append: all_products[producthandles_homme].id
    endif

    if all_products[producthandles_femme] != blank
      assign allinone = allinone | append: ',' | append: all_products[producthandles_femme].id
    endif
  endfor
-%}
```