# Shopify - Logic to display handle of pages, collections, products and index on <body id="handle">?

Tags: shopify, liquid

## Problem

I've found partial answers to this (like [here](https://www.shopify.com/nz/partners/blog/92262598-creating-useful-css-hooks-in-liquid) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67879261/unable-to-get-my-product-ids-after-constructing-the-handle-in-shopify)) but get mixed results because it seems like grabbing the page handle is different depending on if the current page is a collection, a product, a page, a blog or index - is that correct?

Sorry if this is easy, I'm just a designer so am probably using incorrect search terms.

## Attempt

I've been adding logic to the body tag with mixed results like this...

```html
<body 
  {% if template.name != "index" %}id="{{ page.handle }}"{% endif %} 
  class="{{ template }}{% if template == "product" %} {{ product.handle }}{% endif %}
  {% if template == "collection" %} {{ collection.handle }}{% endif %}"
>
```

## Question

If possible, I'd prefer to define a variable like "bodyID" or "bodyClass" and use logic to grab the handle no matter the page-type - is this possible?

Something like...

```html
{%
   bodyID = ...logic to grab handle no matter the page-type...
%}

<body id="{{ bodyID }}"
```

Or is there another way people do this? Any help much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after more searching I found [this](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/handle) and with a bit of logic to handle the index use case, this works and adds a useful ID hook onto the body tag...

```html
<body {% if template.name == "index" %}id="index"{% else %}id="{{ handle }}"{% endif %}>
```

If anyone has a better way, let me know.